# Silverstripe 3 template loops functions and nested loops

Tags: function, loops, controller, nested, silverstripe

Good morning,

I've been struggling with Silverstripe, and it's template parsing with regards to nested loops and functions within loops for a while now, that it's becoming maddening.

If I can get an alternate solution besides ajax (it must be pure php/html/ss), that will be acceptable, thanks.

**[Situation]**
I have 2 Data Objects: ObjectA [*has_many ObjectB*], and ObjectB [*has_one ObjectA*].
I've implemented a tab-pane using CSS-Bootstrap, and would like to display these two objects linked in their respective tabs.

*Example:*
ObjectA_Car is mapped to [ObjectB_Process1, ObjectB_Process2]
ObjectA_Plane is mapped to [ObjectB_Process3, ObjectB_Process4]

**Scenario 1:**
Please see sample pseudo code below:

```
///>sample.ss snippet
<% loop ObjectA_DataList %>
    <div class="tab-pane">
        <h3>$ObjectA_DataList.Title</h3> <!-- Prints ObjectA Title -->
        <hr />
        <h4>$ObjectA_DataList.Description</h4> <!-- Prints ObjectA Description -->
        DEBUG: $Pos <!-- Prints ObjectA loop count/index -->

        <!-- PROBLEM STARTS HERE -->    
        <% loop ObjectB_DataList %>
             DEBUG: ObjectA Count: $Top.Pos <!-- Always prints 1, regardless -->
             DEBUG: ObjectA Count2: $Up.Pos <!-- Same issue as above -->
             DEBUG: $Pos <!-- due to scope, this now prints ObjectB loop count/index -->
        <% end_loop %>
    </div> <!--//#tab-pane-->
<% end_loop %>
```

My aim in the above example was that I was trying to match ObjectA $Pos inside ObjectB loop with an ID that belongs to ObjectB. Not working, because I can't get ObjectA current loop $Pos while inside ObjectB.

**Scenario 2:**
I tried using a function next.

```
///>sample extension code
public function testfn(){
    return "<pre>testfn called!</pre>";
}//testfn

///>sample.ss
$testfn <!-- WORKS OUTSIDE OF LOOP -->
<% loop ObjectA_DataList %>
    $testfn <!-- DOES NOT WORK! -->
<% end_loop %>
```

**Scenario 3**
I got fed up trying to get the above scenarios to work, and then tried using the controller.
So, I've decided to pass an ArrayList to the template an iterate over it with one loop.
But, I can't seem to get the values out. See below:

```
///>sample_controller.php
public function sample(SS_HTTPRequest $request){
    ///... snippet ...
    $buildArr = array();
    foreach($ObjectA as $objA){
       $buildArr[$objA->ID]['objA'] = $objA; //store ObjectA
       $objB = ObjectB::get()->filter(array('Status'=>'Enabled','ObjectA_ID'=>$objA->ID));
       $buildArr[$objA->ID]['objB'] = $objB; //store ObjectB
    }//foreach loop

    $sample_data = new ArrayList($buildArr);
    //if I do a var_dump here, everything looks great.
    //so nothing seems to be the problem with the $sample_data array

    $data = array('mysample' => $sample_data);
    return $this->customise($data)->renderWith(array('sample', 'Page'));
}//sample

///>sample.ss
<% loop mysample %>
      <!-- I don't know how to get the data out -->
      <!-- I've tried $Title, $mysample.Title, $mysample.ObjectA.Title -->
      <!-- nothing seems to work. -->
<% end_loop %>
```

Any assistance provided is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good morning!

I can help you coming to a solution using your scenarios 2 and 3. For the first one I wouldn't know how to address the scope of the first loop correctly.

**Scenario 2**

This one is quite simple. You just need to refer to the general scope Top:

```
///>sample extension code
public function testfn(){
    return "<pre>testfn called!</pre>";
}//testfn

///>sample.ss
$testfn <!-- WORKS OUTSIDE OF LOOP -->
<% loop ObjectA_DataList %>
    $Top.testfn <!-- SHOULD WORK LIKE THIS -->
<% end_loop %>
```

**Scenario 3**

I adjusted the third scenario to get the job done here:

```
///>sample_controller.php
public function sample(SS_HTTPRequest $request){
    // get ObjectA
    $ObjectA = ObjectA::get();

    // run through all ObjectA and add the
    // information from ObjectB to a list of both
    $data = new ArrayList();
    foreach($ObjectA as $objA){
        $objB = ObjectB::get()->filter(array(
            'Status' => 'Enabled',
            'ObjectA_ID' => $objA->ID
        ));
        $data->add(array(
            'ObjA' => $objA,
            'ObjB' => $objB
        ));
    }//foreach loop

    return $this->customise(array('mysample' => $data))
        ->renderWith(array('sample', 'Page'));
}//sample

///>sample.ss
<% loop $mysample %>
    <!-- for a single DataObject -->
    <p>ObjA: $ObjA.ID</p>

    <!-- for a DataList -->
    <% loop $ObjB %>
        <p>ObjB: $ID</p>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_loop %>
```

This approach should work with a single DataObject as well as with a DataList (similar to ArrayList). Depending on which data you add to the ArrayList within the controler you need to adjust your SS-file.

Let me know if you got further questions.

Disclaimer: untested and without any warranty, should still work

Comment: I usually give the money back with interest. That's probably why my incorrect answers are always received very well. But considering scenario 2 & 3 I have to agree with @spekulatius. I am also very interested in scenario 1, as I experienced the same problem. Maybe one could do something with template parts that are returned from a controller, so you can mix template with normal code?

Comment: @spekulatius: Thanks a lot. Both your solutions work.
In scenario 3 you just have a small typo in the beginning with getting $ObjectA. It supposed to be $ObjectA = ObjectA::get(), you made a mistake and assigned B to A, and also the constructor for ArrayList needs an array param. So, new ArrayList() should be new ArrayList(array());

Thanks a million, excellent solution.

Comment: With regards to the latter part of 'jberculo' comment: "Maybe one could do something with template parts that are returned from a controller, so you can mix template with normal code?". I second that. It will help a lot.

Comment: I fixed the ObjectB::get(). About the ArrayList. It can be called with a array or without. "__construct(array $items = array()) {" sets a empty array as default if nothing is given as a parameter. For the scenario #1 I am still thinking about a solution. If I come up I'll add it.

Comment: Any return wrapped in a HTMLCode-Object will be print out. This is often done by using the forTemplate function. You can find more information under: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/silverstripe-dev/Cw8pmtuBd_0 If you got questions regarding this just raise another question :)